# Change django object name

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have `UserDetailsSerializer` class as shown below. I would like to change it's object name from user to data to meet API endpoint requirements on my front-end application. I tried searching through internet but wasn't quite sure how to get such result.

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    uid = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_username')

    """
    User model w/o password
    """
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('uid', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'id')
        read_only_fields = ('email', )

    def get_username(self, obj):
        return obj.username
```

There are few other methods that I could think of, which are reassigning the object in the view with a different name (again, I'm not exactly sure how it works with serializers.) and changing the front-end application API requirement. Please let me know if you can help.

Comment: which current `field` do you want to be represented as `user `?

Comment: What front-end are you using? It seems as though the front-end shouldn't care what your User object is named, but it maybe it just needs the key for the json object to be "data". Does that make sense? like: {"data": {your serialized data}}

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided the content of your view. I believe currently the response dict that your are returning is something like:

```
{'user': UserDetailsSerializer(your_object).data}
```

In this replace the key `user` with `data`.

If that is not the case, please mention where is `user` defined?